# Show the saved value in admin form: right now it is now showing

Tags: adminform, table, edit, default-values

I have an admin form that is saving the data to database but it is not showing the values from database once it saved:

```
 protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $helper = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array('legend' => $helper->__('Select Social Icons'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'facebook',
        'label' => $helper->__('Facebook'),    
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('google', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'google',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('twitter', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'twitter',
        'label' => $helper->__('Twitter'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('yelp', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yelp',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yelp'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('linkedin', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'linkedin',
        'label' => $helper->__('LinkedIn'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('pintrest', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'pintrest',
        'label' => $helper->__('Pintrest'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('gmaps', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'gmaps',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google Map'),
        ));         

    if (Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->getData());
    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

How i can show the value in this form so next time if i save some other values these value that are already in DB not be lost.
[image]

Show Empty value in debug mood:
[image]

Edit action from controller:

```
 <?php

     class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Adminhtml_AdminformController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
      {


      /**
       * View form action
          */
public function indexAction()

{
    $this->_registryObject();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('optfirst/form');
    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Form'), Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Form'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Grid Action
 * Display list of products related to current category
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->_registryObject();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_form_edit')
            ->toHtml()
    );
}

/**
 * Grid Action
 * Display list of products related to current category
 *
 * @return void
 */

     public function saveAction()
       {

       //$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
       if ( $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams() ) {

         $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
           $model =  Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->setData($data);

    //$model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review');
    //print_r($model->getData());

        try {
            $id = 1;
    if ( $id ) {
        $model->load($id);
    }
    $model->addData($data);
    //saves data
    $model->save();

    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
            $this->__('Data was saved'));

    $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);

    if ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('back') ) {
        $params = array('id' => $model->getId());
        $this->_redirect('*/*/', $params);
    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
    if ( $model && $model->getId() ) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/', array(
            'id' => $model->getId()
        ));
    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}


    return;
       }
//if no data has been passed an error will be thrown and user redirected
$this->_getSession()->addError($this__('No data found to save'));
$this->_redirect('*/*');
     }

         /**
        * registry form object
         */
         protected function _registryObject()
            {
         Mage::register('optfirst_reviewmycompany', Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review'));
          }

         }
```

Comment: can you post the edit action from your controller?

Comment: @Marius Here is the code:
 public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->_registryObject();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_form_edit')
                ->toHtml()
        );
    }

Comment: and the _registryObject? In fact it is better to add the full controller in your question. It's easier to figure things out?

Comment: @Marius♦ Please check the updated question now

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end :

```
$this->setForm($form);
return parent::_prepareForm();
```

Comment: Already tried but not worked, Still showing the blank form  @Ashish Jagnani

Answer (score 0):

fir create your registry object in your form action.

```
public function indexAction()

{
    $this->_registryObject();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('optfirst/form');
    $this->_registryObject();
    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Form'), Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Form'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
protected function _registryObject()
    {
     $id=$this->getRequest()->geParam('id');
     $data=Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->load($id);
     Mage::register('optfirst_reviewmycompany', $data);
      }
```

Comment: I have followed the answer but its giving the error:
 Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::geParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\extension-development\app\code\community\OptFirst\ReviewMyCompany\controllers\Adminhtml\AdminformController.php on line 123

Comment: do you have any other solution for this issue?

Comment: @Xabby change this `$id=$this->getRequest()->geParam('id');` to `$id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');`

Comment: Still the same issue, blank form values. actually i already corrected that mistake..

Comment: enable the error log u can get the then it is easy to understand

Comment: now there is not any error, its just showing the blank fields in the form

Comment: check values in controller first then block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51371/discussion-between-xabby-and-qaisar-satti).